# Elasticsearch insensitive search accents

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I'm using Elastic search with Python. I can't find a way to make insensitive search with accents.

For example:
I have two words. "**Camión**" and "**Camion**".
When a user search for "camion" I'd like the two results show up.

Creating index:

```
es = Elasticsearch([{u'host': u'127.0.0.1', u'port': b'9200'}])

es.indices.create(index='name', ignore=400)

es.index(
    index="name",
    doc_type="producto",
    id=p.pk,
    body={
        'title': p.titulo,
        'slug': p.slug,
        'summary': p.summary,
        'description': p.description,
        'image': foto,
        'price': p.price,
        'wholesale_price': p.wholesale_price,
        'reference': p.reference,
        'ean13': p.ean13,
        'rating': p.rating,
        'quantity': p.quantity,
        'discount': p.discount,
        'sales': p.sales,
        'active': p.active,
        'encilleria': p.encilleria,
        'brand': marca,
        'brand_title': marca_titulo,
        'sellos': sellos_str,
        'certificados': certificados_str,
        'attr_naturales': attr_naturales_str,
        'soluciones': soluciones_str,
        'categories': categories_str,
        'delivery': p.delivery,
        'stock': p.stock,
        'consejos': p.consejos,
        'ingredientes': p.ingredientes,
        'es_pack': p.es_pack,
        'temp': p.temp,
        'relevancia': p.relevancia,
        'descontinuado': p.descontinuado,
    }
```

Search:

```
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
    es = Elasticsearch([{'host': '127.0.0.1', 'port': '9200'}])

    resul = es.search(
        index="name",
        body={
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "(title:" + search + " OR description:" + search + " OR summary:" + search + ") AND (active:true)",
                    "analyze_wildcard": False
                }
            },
            "size": "9999",
        }
    )
    print resul
```

I've searched on Google, Stackoverflow and elastic.co but I didn't find anything that works.

Comment: What's the mapping for those fields you use in your query?

Comment: Do you mean in the database? All strings. Do I have to declare anything on the query?

Comment: What database? :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm new with elastic. I mean the index. I've updated the question with all my code. =)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to change the mapping of those fields you have in the query. Changing the mapping requires re-indexing so that the fields will be analyzed differently and the query will work.

Basically, you need something like the following below. The field called `text` is just an example. You need to apply the same settings for other fields as well. Note that I used `fields` in there so that the root field will maintain the original text analyzed by default, while `text.folded` will remove the accented characters and will make it possible for your query to work. I have also changed the query a bit so that you search both versions of that field (`camion` will match, but also `camión`).

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "folding": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "folded": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "folding"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the query:

```
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "\\*.folded:camion"
    }
  }
```

Also, I strongly suggest reading this section of the documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/asciifolding-token-filter.html

Comment: I've seen something like this. But where do I put this code? Before the body{} on es.index()?

Comment: I don't know Python. Sorry. That code I provided creates the index with those settings and that mapping. So, the existent index needs to be deleted, that code I provided used to create a new index, data needs to be reindexed.

Comment: @AndreiStefan thanks this seems still to be valid in ES 7.14, but the doc is out dated.