# elasticsearch ignore accents on search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-analyzers

I have an elasticsearch index with customer informations

I have some issues looking for some results with accents

for example, I have `{name: 'anais'}` and `{name: anaïs}`

Running

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
  "size": 25, 
  "query": {
    "match": {"name": "anaïs"}
  }
}
```

I would like to get both same for this query, in this case I only have `anaïs`

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
  "size": 25, 
  "query": {
    "match": {"name": "anais"}
  }
}
```

I would like to get `anais` and `anaïs`, in this case I only have `anais`

I tried adding an `analyser`

```
PUT /my-new-celebrity/_settings
{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "default": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "asciifolding"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But in this case for both search I only get `anais`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452791/elasticsearch-insensitive-search-accents

Comment: @HariRao I tried this one with {query:{match:{"name.folded":"anais"}}} before and after reindexing and I have empty results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to apply your custom `default` analyzer on your `name` field, below is working example:

**Index def with mapping and setting**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "default": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "properties" :{
            "name" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "analyzer" : "default" // note this 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample docs**

```
{
   "name" : "anais"
}

{
   "name" : "anaïs"
}
```

**Search query same as yours**

```
{
    "size": 25,
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": "anaïs"
        }
    }
}
```

**And expected both search results**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "myindexascii",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.18232156,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "anaïs"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "myindexascii",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.18232156,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "anais"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: `asciifolding` doesn't seem to work for Greek on OpenSearch, from what I can see. It only works for Latin letters. I am not sure if ElasticSearch is any different. :(